# Insert function not working with 2 if statements C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and am confused why this line of code is not working.

```
if(choice == 1){
    if(mp[name] == 0){
        mp.insert(make_pair(name, marks));
        cout << 1;
    }
```

The whole program is listed below.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
  
int main() 
{ 
  
    // initialize container 
    map<string, int> mp, mp1; 
    int choice, marks;
    string name;
    cin >> choice;
    cin >> name;
    cin >> marks;
    if(choice == 1){
        if(mp[name] == 0){
            mp.insert(make_pair(name, marks));
            cout << 1;
        } else {
            mp[name] += marks;
        }
    }
    mp1.insert(mp.begin(), mp.end());
    for(auto itr = mp1.begin(); itr != mp1.end(); ++itr){
        cout << itr->first << '\t' << itr->second << '\n';
    }
    cout << mp1[name];
    return 0;
}
```

The error seems to be in the double if statement. When running the code, the if statements is executed because a 1 is printed. However the insert command is never executed. If I eliminate the if statement, the insert command seems to work fine. I have been seeking an answer for hours to no avail. I am new to C++ and StackOverflow so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? As described in the documentation of [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at): "_Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, **performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.**_" (emphasis mine) So your `insert` call doesn't do anything, since such element always exist, when you call it.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I understand now.

Comment: so as a solution you can replace `if(mp[name] == 0)` with `if(mp.count(name) == 0)`

Comment: Since `mp[name]` will initialise to 0 if it doesn’t exist, you don’t need to check. Just do `mp[name] += marks;`, unconditionally.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of not defining variables until they are needed. In this case, that means don't define `mp1` at the top of the function. Instead, change `mp1.insert(...)` to `map<string, int> mp1 = mp;`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

```
map<string, int> mp, mp1;
```

You declared a map, but never intialized the values of map, remember this is C++, there is no default intializer, also

```
if(mp[name] == 0){
            mp.insert(make_pair(name, marks));
            cout << 1;
        }
```

Is not going to run, like 99.99% of the time.... Unless you get super lucky and somehow the undefined behavior intializes the value to 0.

Comment: operator[] will value-initialize the value if the key is not present (via `value_type(key, mapped_type())`, so it is guarenteed to be 0...

Comment: Are you sure, cause if you try int num; and you go cout << num; you will get some non sense values

Comment: That is default-initialized -- the map case is value-initialized.  There's a difference in the semantics.  Try using `int num = int();` and see what happens.  See section 8.5 in the C++ spec.

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem has already been told in the comments, I suggest you use `std::map::find`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
  
int main() 
{ 
  std::map<std::string, int> mp;
  mp["ex"] = 0;
  auto it = mp.find("ex");
  
  if(it != mp.end())
  {
      it->second = 1;
  }
  std::cout << mp["ex"]; // Outputs 1
}
```

This searches for an iterator of which the first value in the pair is "ex", checks if it's not equal to the last iterator (it's the default value if no such iterator is found), initializes the 2nd value in the pair to 1, then outputs it.
For more information about `std::map::find` [visit this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/)